Support under the plywood and granite countertop
I bought a Bosch dishwasher, the height doesn't fit into the space where an existing dishwasher is placed. It's 1/4'' short.
I have a granite countertop supported by plywood underneath, and 2 "beams", one at the front as part of face frame, another at the back as cabinet back. Here is an image for what I'm talking about (the red circled pieces) https://imgur.com/K9dtk8H. I don't have drawer, door and shelf as in the image, instead I have an existing dishwasher in place. The new dishwasher can fit in if I cut and remove these 2 beams.
I wonder if it is safe to do that. Are they supporting the countertop as well?

I have that exact setup; it is fine.  In fact, when I remodeled the kitchen, no cabinet was placed where dishwasher slides in.


In fact, it seems odd for a cabinet to have been installed where the d/w is going to go.

It’s very conventional to not have a top rail where the dishwasher goes. (Even to the point of there being no cabinet there, just a gap.)
So removing those pieces should be fine, with the caution that the adjacent cabinets need to be solidly attached to the wall. They may have been relying on this cabinet for structure. Try removing only the front one first and see if the dishwasher fits.
